# How should the function "isSpanningTree()" look like?

Tags: graph, spanning-tree

Write a program that simulates a positional game, such as the connectivity game, between a given number of players.

At the beginning of the game the board contains all the edges of a complete graph with n vertices (all the pairs formed with distinct numbers from 1 to n). 
Each player extracts edges successively from the board and must create with them a spanning tree of the initial complete graph. 
The game ends when either a player makes a spanning tree (in this case the winner receives n points and the others 0) or when all edges have been removed from the graph (in this case each player receives a number of points equal to the number of vertices of their largest partial tree). 
I have to consider the situation when the player choose random an edge and when a "smart" player should try to extend its maximal tree while not allowing others to create a spanning tree.

Comment: Rather than bluntly asking a question that very much looks like "Please do my homework for me", you may want to specify what you tried so far, and what issue you encountered.

Comment: I just ask for an idea not for the entire code.

Comment: Did you at least google 'spanning tree algorithm'?